# How do we know $\psi$ depends on $n,l,m$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, atomic-physics, hydrogen

Regarding the separation of $\psi$ to an angular and radial part, why does each part have a specific dependence of the quantum numbers? How can Schrodinger equation describe a system just from its energy?

**What I mean is**: the wavefunction $\psi$ for the hydrogen atom can be separated into two parts: the radial part and the angular part. For the radial part, it's a function that depends only on the principal quantum number $n$ and the azimuthal number $\ell$. For the angular part, it's another function that depend on the  azimuthal number $\ell$ and the magnetic number $m$.
$$
\psi(\mathbf r)=R_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)
$$

The question is: why does each function have a particular dependence on these quantum numbers?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking here

Comment: Please clarify your *specific* problem or add additional details to highlight *exactly* what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It's still unclear what your question is. Why do you say that the "solution to the Schrödinger equation" doesn't have a physical meaning? The product of the angular and radial part *is* the solution, and has perfectly clear meaning! The functions with definite $n,l,m$ are just the function with definite energies, and hence the solutions to the time-independent Schrödinger equation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I think he means that *wavefunction* $\psi$ has no meaning, not that the solution (the energy eigenvalues) has no meaning.

Comment: Well,that's exactly the problem,because i found a contradiction between the answers given by a lot of college professors that i asked;some say that ψ does not have a physical meaning and others say it's the description of the atomic orbitals for the hydrogen atom,while others say it's the Schrodinger equation that has no meaning but the solution ψ has a significance by its own.

Comment: @NoureddineBouhali: at the end of the day, the meaning is in the formalism.  I think everyone would agree that $\psi$ contains more information than what can be physically extracted, and some of this "extra" information is unphysical stuff like phase.  At the end of the day, though, if you know what $\psi$ is for a system, you can calculate any physical quantity you want.  If you try and go much deeper than that, you'll get stuck asking questions like "what is real?" that can have many answers depending on how you define "what", "is" and "real".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantum numbers serve to enumerate the solutions to the time-independent Schrodinger equation (Energy eigenstates) which are also eigenstates of the angular momentum (squared) operator and have a definite component of angular momentum in some direction labeled $ z $. When solving the problem, it just turns out to be handy to label the solutions with the quantum numbers.

There are a countably infinite number of solutions to the radial part of the equation, and it also turns out that the radial part completely determines the total energy of the state. So we label those radial solutions by the principal quantum number $ n $ where $ \in \mathbb N_+$. The radial equation however can take multiple forms for a given energy and will vary depending on angular momentum. That's where the $\ell $ comes in.

$\ell$ can vary from $ 0$ to $ n-1$ and this totally determines the magnitude of angular momentum, and $ m$ can vary from $-\ell $ to $\ell $ and this totally determines the $ z $ component of angular momentum. These two characteristics determine the angular part of the equation and so the angular equation solutions are indexed by $\ell $ and $ m $.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question comes from math, not from physics.  Consider the wave equation in 1+1 dimensions:

$$\partial^{2}_{x}\phi(x,t) - \partial^{2}_{t}\phi = 0$$

One obvious way to solve this is to convert the PDE in two variables into two ODEs in one variable.  This is done by assuming that the solution can be written as some sum

$$\phi(x,t) = \sum_{i} T_{i}(t)X_{i}(x)$$

Now, plugged into our equation, we have

$$\sum_{i}\left(T_{i}(t)X_{i}^{\prime \prime}(x) - X_{i}(x){\ddot T_{i}}(t)\right) = 0$$

where prime denotes derivative with respect to x and dot denotes derivative with respect to t, and I distributed the sum out.  Now, it turns out that you can show that it is always possible to expand out this series in such a way that each term has to be zero, but here, we will assume this.  In this case, we then have:

$$T_{i}(t)X_{i}^{\prime \prime}(x) = X_{i}(x){\ddot T_{i}}(t)$$

for each $i$.  Dividing by $TX$, we get:

$$\frac{X_{i}^{\prime \prime}(x)}{X(x)} =\frac{{\ddot T_{i}}(t)}{T(t)}$$

Since the left hand side depends only on t, and the right hand side depends only on x, then changing the value of t while holding the value of x constant would break this equality, unless both sides were equal to a constant.  We call this constant $n_{i}$, and we have:

$$\frac{X_{i}^{\prime \prime}(x)}{X(x)} =\frac{{\ddot T_{i}}(t)}{T(t)} = n_{i}$$

And we have officially broken our pde into two ODEs.  And the cost we paid was to acquire a seperation constant.  This constant is exactly the same sort of thing that you get in quantum mechanics when solving the hydrogen atom.  Except, you have to do this three times, and thus, you get the quantum numbers $n,\ell,$ and $m$.